# Intuition of local connection forms

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

In the past I had the feeling that I understood the mathematics and ideas behind principal connections and connection one-forms rather well. However, while trying to explain these ideas in simple terms to a nonmathematical audience, I noticed that my understanding might not extend flawlessly beyond the pure formulas.

When you have a principal $G$-bundle $\pi:P\rightarrow M$, you can canonically define the vertical subbundle as the kernel of the projection $\pi_*$. A connection is then equivalent to a choice of complement inside the tangent bundle $TP$. Locally, where $P|_U\cong U\times G$, one can identify the vertical spaces with the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. A complement can then be defined by assigning to every basis $\partial_i$ of a tangent space on $M$ a ''horizontal lift'' $$\widetilde{\partial}_i:=\partial_i+\chi_i,$$ where $\chi_i\in\mathfrak{g}$ (these two terms should be mapped in the right way to a tangent space of $P|_U$ and extended to a local frame).

The associated connection one-form $\omega$ on $P$ is then, as far as I understand, the form that assigns to any vector field on $P$, at any point, the contribution in $\mathfrak{g}$ that does not arise from these $\chi_i$'s: $$X = \sum_i\lambda_i(\partial_i+\chi_i) + \omega(X),$$ for some scalars numbers $\lambda_i$. It measures the change in the fibres that does not arise from a mere change on the base manifold.

When we then, locally, pullback the connection one-form $\omega$ to a one-form on the patch $U$, we get $$A = s^*\omega.$$ By definition of the pullback I would then think that this evaluates to the following formula on any vector field: $A(Y) = \omega(s_*Y)$. By then combining the above statements, I would expect that $A$ assigns to any vector field on $M$ the difference between its pushforward (along a section) to the bundle and its horizontal lift, resulting in a linear combination of the $\chi_i$'s. Is this correct?

Comment: I haven't read the details of your question, but I encourage anyone who is trying to understand how a connection on a principal bundle works to first learn about a connection on a vector bundle. This in turn defines a natural connection on the bundle of frames of the vector bundle, by applying the connection to each section in the frame. In that setting it is, at least for me, a lot easier to derive the formulas for a connection on a principal $GL(k)$-bundle since the action of $G$ on the frame bundle is quite explicit. After that, it's not hard to translate everything into the abstract case.

Comment: I know about the situation on vector bundles and how one obtains the formulas. These are not the problem. Its rather how to obtain a simple interpretation of what the local one-forms do.

Comment: I would support Deane's suggestion specifically with what you're saying. Think of the case where $P$ is the frame bundle (say orthonormal frames). Then when you pull back by a section you're looking specifically at how the frame is twisting. If $s(x)=(e_i(x))$, then $s^*\omega = (\omega_{ij}(x))$ and $\nabla e_i = \sum\omega_{ij}e_j$. You can interpret this, of course, in terms of local parallel frame fields.

Comment: @TedShifrin I know that this is indeed what the connection does. But i want to relate this to definition in terms of horizontal vectors. But I guess this more or less boils down to this. It says how much the pushforward of a frame has to change to become a locally parallel frame, no?

Comment: Right. Twisting by the negative of $(s^*\omega)_p(Y)$ makes the frame $s(p)$ parallel as you move instantaneously in direction $Y$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok, so that's indeed the intuition I had (whether its in terms of parallel frames or of general horizontal lifts). But then I was confused with the fact that it is indeed the negative of this pullback that makes it parallel, while in the formula for the covariant derivative (which takes the change along the horizontal lift) we used the positive sign. Has this something to do with active vs passive transformation (changing the coefficients vs changing the frame)?

Comment: I don't think there's any contradiction. I'm saying that if you are driving along turning to the left, then you must compensate by turning to the right in order to go straight. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin First of all, thanks for the help. I just found out why I couldnt unite the intuitive idea of "compensation" with the formula for covariant derivatives. I failed to realise that the derivative along the fundamental vector field (the part characterized by $\omega$) is MINUS the action of the corresponding Lie algebra element. The different minuses confused me...

Comment: This doesn't sound right. It sounds like left/right action issues.